# Unable to log in with provided credentials django DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

My first time trying django REST api , I am doing some athentification , now i facing this error whene i run this commande  :  [curl -X POST -d "username=&password=" http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/auth/login/] 
error : {"non_field_errors":["Unable to log in with provided credentials."]}

views.py :

```
class CreateUserAPIView(CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = CreateUserSerializer
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        # We create a token than will be used for future auth
        token = Token.objects.create(user=serializer.instance)
        token_data = {"token": token.key}
        return Response(
            {**serializer.data, **token_data},
            status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED,
            headers=headers
        )
```

serializers.py

```
class CreateUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    username = serializers.CharField()
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True,
                                     style={'input_type': 'password'})

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ('username', 'password', 'first_name', 'last_name')
        write_only_fields = ('password')
        read_only_fields = ('is_staff', 'is_superuser', 'is_active',)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = super(CreateUserSerializer, self).create(validated_data)
        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.save()
        return user
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('auth/login/',
        obtain_auth_token,
        name='auth_user_login'),
    path('auth/register/',
        CreateUserAPIView.as_view(),
        name='auth_user_create'),
    path('auth/logout/',
        LogoutUserAPIView.as_view(),
        name='auth_user_logout')
]
```

Comment: Your're using `curl` on the wrong endpoint, your example is `auth/login/` while the creation one is `auth/register/`, can you verify this?

Comment: i doing this tutorial ,https://afdezl.github.io/post/authentication-react-native-django-1/ , i confused now ??

Comment: What are you confused about? Where are you stuck there, point us so that we can help you

Comment: i did exactly the same thing in the turtorial , but its not working ??

Comment: I've posted an answer did it helped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorial you've pointed requires you to [create a superuser](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/django-admin/#createsuperuser) in [section 1.2](https://afdezl.github.io/post/authentication-react-native-django-1/#1-2-configuring-the-application-settings), so create one for yourself and then use those informations on your login.

In your terminal you will type: `python manage.py createsuperuser`

Then you will be prompted as follows:

```
Username (leave blank to use 'ubuntu'): <YOUR_USERNAME>
Email address: <email> // you can leave it as blank
Password: <YOUR_PASSWORD>
Password (again): <YOUR_PASSWORD>
```

Then call again, replacing those values between <> with your input values:

```sh
curl -X POST -d "username=<YOUR_USERNAME>&password=<YOUR_PASSWORD>" http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/auth/login/
```

Comment: thank you, but I did exactly the same thing , not working

Comment: @itjuba Can you share your INSTALLED_APPS?

Answer (score 0):

Adding this in settings.py fixed it for me

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",
    "allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend"
)
```